# minted and tcolorbox: putting code in the title

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, code

I suppose it's meant to be used like this:
[image]

But sometimes I like to use the title section to represent code or a command or some kind of input, and show the output in the bottom section like this: 
[image]
The problem is the typesetting (no monospace, weird quotes, etc.), no syntax highlighting, LaTeX interprets various commands & special characters (e.g. `$`, `&`, `#`, `^`, `_`, `\\`) and trying to use `\verb` is problematic (`LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.`).

Any ideas? Thanks. Here's the code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[margin=10,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[minted,most]{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\textbf{echo 'hello, world'}]
\begin{minted}{bash}
hello, world
\end{minted}
\end{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\textbf{hello\_world.sh}]
\begin{minted}{bash}
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'hello, world'
\end{minted}
\end{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: A less painfull approach would be utilize "upper" and "lower" part of tcolorbox (access via \tcblower); you can also have a subtitle in each box.

Comment: @TomášKruliš You're right, that might be better. Would you care to demonstrate? I see a few things like what you describe in the manual, but what you describe sounds even better.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution using a `listing and comment` and `bicolor` box. Upper box shows the listing and lower one the `comment` which is the expected result.

The `overlay` line tries to mimic the geometry of a regular tcolorbox with title and upper part.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[margin=10,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[minted,most]{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\textbf{echo 'hello, world'}]
\begin{minted}{bash}
hello, world
\end{minted}
\end{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\textbf{hello\_world.sh}]
\begin{minted}{bash}
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'hello, world'
\end{minted}
\end{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tcblisting}{notitle, 
    listing and comment,
    bicolor,
    colback=black!75!white,
    colbacklower=black!5!white,
    top=0mm, middle=1mm,
    overlay={\draw[line width=1.05mm, black!5!white, opacity=1] ([shift={(.5mm,1mm)}]frame.west)--([shift={(-.5mm,1mm)}]frame.east);},
    comment={hello, world}, 
    colupper=white,
    fontlower=\ttfamily,}
echo 'hello, world'
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]